# System of equalities and inequalities is NP-hard using a reduction from 3COLORING

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np-hard, 3-sat

We are require to show that a problem  where the input is a system of equalities and inequalities, each involving polynomials of degree at most 2 (with integer coefficients) in n real variables x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub>. The problem is to decide whether there exists an assignment to x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>, ..., x<sub>n</sub> that satisfies all the constraints simultaneously. I need to show that the following problem is NP-hard by reducing from the **3COLORING** problem.

For example:

x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> ≤ 1

x<sub>1</sub> ≥ 0

x<sub>2</sub> ≥ 0

4<sub>x1</sub><sub>x2</sub> ≥ 1

is solvable if I choose x<sub>1</sub> = x<sub>2</sub> =1/2.

I'm have some issue in coming up with a valid reduce from 3coloring to this. If any one of you can provide me some tips that would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express any boolean formula using a (polynomial-size) system of quadratic equalities. Indeed you can force a variable $x$ to be binary by writing $x^2 = x$, and you can force a binary variable $z$ to be the NAND of two binary variables $x$ and $y$ by writing $z = 1 - xy$ (recall that NAND is a universal operation. Anyway it is easy to come up with explicit formulas for AND, OR, and NOTs).

Then you just need to write a (polynomial-size) boolean formula that is satisfied if and only if the input instance of graph 3 coloring is a yes-instance. This should be straightforward.